# specific element in array from array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array like

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}, etc.]
```

How can i retrive an array with only id like?

```
myArrayResult = [73,45]
```

with jQuery or javascript.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
myArrayResult = myArray.map(function (el) {
   return el.id;  // if you want get id as Number, just add +el.id
})
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/socena/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var myArrayResult = myArray.map(function (item) {
    return item.id;
}
```

Or if you don't have a true browser (ie. IE8 or less)

```
var myArrayResult = [];

for (var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {
    myArrayResult.push(myArray[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];

myArrayResult=[];
$.each(myArray,function(index,val){
     myArrayResult.push(val.id);
});
alert(myArrayResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```